# Windows Remote Desktop on UHD monitor, how to scale the RDP window itself, and not on the remote host?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, resolution, high-definition

**Context**

I changed my monitor to an UHD monitor, using it 3840x2160 (UHD) native resolution, and scale my windows, to make text and icons to an ergonomic size.

**Issue**

When I am connecting to my remote Azure Windows (Server) desktops, I am facing with the choice what should be the RDP resolution?

a) RDP resolution HD (1920x1080). This case the whole RDP window will be the quarter area of my screen, which makes the UX poor, and makes 3/4 of my screen unused...

b) configuring RDP resolution to UHD (3840x2160) and scale the *remote* computer's desktop will give very similar full screen experience as the local desktop... however it is significantly poorer performance, time machine back to 10 years despite of 100G/s connection on my side 1000G/s on remote side. I suppose this is because of two reasons, first is itself the RDP, which must code/decode and transfer 4x bigger area, plus the remote machine is not optimized to serve UHD resolution...

In many use cases using UHD for RDP is overkill, both for the transmission component, both for the remote host itself. However the scenario will occur more and more as the local desktops and monitors are shifting to UHD.

**Question**

How can I see a full screen, remote desktop in my RDP window, what is coming from an normal HD remote, with normal HD RDP resolution, and scaled up to UHD in my local host?

Comment: In your case a), what happens if you resize the RDP window up?

Comment: many thx for your question. In case a) I can not resize it bigger than the quarter area of my UHD screen. Even I maximize the window it will the quarter area, if I switch to "full screen" then I got a black bordered full screen, with middle aligned 1920x1080 screen... :-(